# How am I getting a 'card-error' using Stripe Orders API when creating an order?

Tags: stripe-payments, orders

Using Stripe Orders API, the create order method can return a 'card_error' despite not being able to give or handle any credit card information.

error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "order_creation_failed",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/order-creation-failed",
    "message": "Order creation failed while contacting the provider.",
    "type": "card_error"
  }
}
```

How can I get a 'card_error' when there is no support to add card information when creating a Stripe Order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have opted to use your own way of calculating the tax or shipping an error thrown or returned from that could result in a 'card_error' since it was unable to create the order's line items. The error code isn't particularly great but it is testable and repeatable.

In this case, the shipping or tax calculation returns a float rather than an int then this would be the error returned. Stripe likes everything in cents (for USD) so 1750.5 cents breaks their calculation. Wrapping with parseInt(itemAmount*tax) would solve that of course.